# Trying to use a proxy with Watir... (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, google-chrome, watir

I have a few proxies I want to use with my Watir integration that use authentication. There is no documentation for auth with proxies (http://watir.com/guides/proxies/). From a previous SO article, I read that it's supposed to be in this format:

```
proxy = {
      http: 'http://user:pass@35.197.175.20:3128',
      ssl:  'https://user:pass@35.197.175.20:3128'
    }
```

I create my browser object with the proxy like this: `browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true, proxy: proxy`

What am I doing wrong? Why isn't it routing the connection through the proxy?

Answer (score 1):

Watir is largely based on selenium. Selenium does not support authorization with proxying as of the time of this posting.

An issue has been brought up https://github.com/watir/watir/issues/798 but nothing has come of it yet. Possibly in the future; but I would suggest looking at alternative methods for right now.